# Modify database schema via entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have an existing database and I am operating on data inside it via a .NET C# application using ADO.NET currently. I am suggested to use Entity Framework model. However, I want to add some stored procedures and tables to the database and use them when the compiled application runs. Can I create entity-framework model for current database without these to-be-added stored procedures and tables and then add those during runtime when using the compiled application?

Is it possible with entity framework model? Can someone give me some pointers about how to do this? I am new to entity framework.

Comment: I want to add those stored procedures and tables from within the application only. Is it possible to do with entity-framework itself?

Comment: Why do you need to add them at runtime? How do you expect to create and use them later? What kind of functionality will they implement?

Comment: You would need to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and then select your database tables. However, it gives you the option to add in the stored procedures there and then. I don't see why you would need to add them at runtime since you can import them into your project and call them as functions in your code.